# Adding onclick event to call certain hyperlink in rapahael

Tags: javascript

Based on demo http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html, I want to add onclick event to the demo. My idea is that, whenever user click on certain state, it directs to certain website. For example, if user click on New South Wales, I want user to be directed to a website http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_South_Wales.

Could anyone share some solution?

Thanks in advance.
Sharad

Comment: you could add this part of code: st[0].onclick = function(){ //anything you want to do on click } after onmouseout event.

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate? I have seven different websiteaddress and seven states. I can't just figure out how to tell rapahel to pick the correct web address.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

first put all links and stort terms for states (same as div id) into assoc array:

```
var links = { 'nsw':'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_South_Wales','sa':'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Australia'}; //i am too lazy to find all links, just fill till the end in same style
```

then call this method after onmouseevent (in index page):

```
st[0].onclick = function(){ 
    window.open(links[current]); //current contain same value as div id (for example wa for Western Australia. this would open new window. 
}
```